# Why Back Button is hidden in Maui?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net MAUI application with Page A and Page B.

I want to move from Page A >>> Page B.

When I move using the following code, I have a back button (which is the desired behavior in my case) :

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage());
```

However if I move to the other page using the following code, I don't have a back button :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MyPage");
```

For some other reasons I need to use navigation through Shell.

Why don't I have a back button when navigating using Shell?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for your answer but I don't agree with you. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer :

Instead of

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MyPage");
```

I should do

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/MyPage");
```

Reason :

According to the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation) :

```
route : The route hierarchy will be searched for the specified route, upwards from the current position. The matching page will be pushed to the navigation stack.
/route : The route hierarchy will be searched from the specified route, downwards from the current position. The matching page will be pushed to the navigation stack.
//route : The route hierarchy will be searched for the specified route, upwards from the current position. The matching page will replace the navigation stack.
///route : The route hierarchy will be searched for the specified route, downwards from the current position. The matching page will replace the navigation stack.
```