# dotnet maui how to hide the back button on desktop?

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I'm trying to hide the backbutton shown in the image on desktop, but no matter what I tried, then it keept showing up.

I have tried

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

And I have tried following this SO post [Why Back Button is hidden in Maui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101820/why-back-button-is-hidden-in-maui)

My navigation is done by saying `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(new ShellNavigationState(location), false);`

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This technique (the code in your question), added within the <ContentPage ... > declaration at the top of the xaml:

```
<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior IsVisible="False" IsEnabled="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

seems to work when using the Shell to activate pages in C# codebehind (often in the BindingSource e.g., viewmodel):

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(MyContentPage)}");
```

Adding this within the <ContentPage ...> declaration at the top of the xaml:

```
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="false"
```

seems to be applicable when using the push/pop within a NavigationPage:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage());
```

I don't use the Navigation.PushAsync.  My app requires very specific navigation based on current data state, so a stack doesn't work for me.
I have verified setting the Shell.BackButtonBehavior (in the very code you provided) works in my case because I am activating pages via

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync
```

Comment: Correct spelling in answer.

Answer (score 4):

So everything you need to know can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage

```
NavigationPage.HasBackButton = true/false
```

**Image (Proof)**
https://gyazo.com/afbc744e7b6c5d1caa56960a536390c7

If this was helpful, mark this please as answer :)

Comment: This is not working for me. What am I missing?? 
https://gyazo.com/315929b52422ddd1df95cb5b1edbde8e

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable something you can use OnPlatform or OnIdiom
Exemple :

```
NavigationPage.HasBackButton="{OnIdiom Default='True', Desktop='False'}"
```