# The MAUI navigation bar back button stuck

Tags: xamarin, maui

My application navigation bar back button is sometimes going to stuck
**I have applied**

```
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" with XAML page and NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);in code behind
```

but it's not properly working. Is there the best solution for that?

Comment: Have you tried `<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">`  in you XAML definition ?

Comment: @Poulpynator.Yes.tried

Comment: Maybe you have a `NavigationPage` inside the `Shell` (or severals shells inside each others) ? It will be hard to tell without more information

Comment: @Poulpynator yes that's inside the Shell

Comment: Maybe `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"` ?

Comment: @Poulpynator.When use Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False totally remove the Navigation Bar.Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252844/discussion-between-dotnetdeveloper22-and-poulpynator).

Comment: Sorry, I know I am on stackoverflow but I am not that free x) have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73373401/dotnet-maui-how-to-hide-the-back-button-on-desktop ?

Answer (score 1):

In Maui's shell navigation, you can use BackButtonBehavior to modify the back button. If you need to hide the button, you can set IsEnabled to false. Refer to the following code:

```
  <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
      <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False"/>
  </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
```

For more information, please refer to the official documentation: [Back button behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0#back-button-behavior)